# How can I use Same SSRS Report Set for different database instances?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a set of 10 reports that we use on multiple instances of our software, currently I create a copy of each report for every database instance.

Is there any way for me to resolve the issue of creating seperate copies, I need just one report set and dynamic datasource switching as per the datasource.

I am expecting a centralized report set that switches as per the instance I am using.

Comment: so you need a dynamic data source in SSRS. Did you google "Dynamic datasource SSRS"?

Comment: Look at this. It has no accepted answers but does give some options. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74303753/pull-the-same-report-from-different-databases/74306989#74306989